# Date to json number after date

Tags: javascript, json

When i try to serialize a javascript date object to json, with JSON.stringify(), i get something like

```
"2014-10-27T15:00:00.000Z"
```

What is the T15 after 27 ? Is there a way to get always T00 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` appears in that string to indicate the beginning of time element, so `T15:00:00`, means 15 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds, so its `THH:mm:ss`

If you want to set hours, minutes and seconds to 0, then with javascript you could use [setHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours), as

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

It will set time to `00:00:00.000` of your timezone

Comment: why when i try to serialize this Sun Apr 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern Europe Daylight Time), it returns "2015-04-25T21:00:00.000Z" ? i wan't "2015-04-26T00:00:00.000Z"

Comment: the 'Z' denotes Universal time (GMT), since GMT offset it +3 hours, i.e Eastern Europe Daylight Time is 3 hours ahead of GMT, you get 21:00:00, i.e. 21 hours

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify uses toJSON javascript Date method. It returns an ISO-formatted date string for the UTC time zone (denoted by the suffix Z). So, if you want to get 00 hours, you have to set it by `setUTCHours`:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/zkmfax6h/) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!